# I can't figure out how to write to my data to a csv file as well as having my sorting code function correctly

Tags: python, csv

```
if class_number == ('1') and sort_by == ('a') or ('A'):

    csv_file = open('Class1_Test_Score.csv', 'a')
    csv_file.write('\n')
    csv_file.write(sname + ' ' + fname)
    csv_file.write(',')
    csv_file.write(score)
    csv_file.close()

    sort1 = open('Class1_Test_Score.csv', 'r')
    sorting = csv.reader(sort1, delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(sorting,key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    for eachline in sort:
        csv_file.write(eachline)
```

Comment: You're closing your file before trying to write to it.

Comment: I've changed the code to as follows:  if class_number == ('1') and sort_by == ('a') or ('A'):
                    
    csv_file = open('Class1_Test_Score.csv', 'a')
    csv_file.write('\n')
    csv_file.write(sname + ' ' + fname)
    csv_file.write(',')
    csv_file.write(score)

    sort1 = open('Class1_Test_Score.csv', 'r')
    sorting = csv.reader(sort1, delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(sorting,key=operator.itemgetter(0))

    for eachline in sort:
        csv_file.write(eachline)

    csv_file.close()

Comment: But i still receive this error message: sort = sorted(sorting,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Is every row in your Nested List its own list object with length greater than 0 ?

The majority of your rows are likely list objects with multiple items, giving it a :

```
    len ( row ) > 1
```

But I'm guessing there may be at least one Row in your Nested List that has a length of 0. In other words whereas most of your rows look like this :

```
    [  'First Item' ,  2  ,  "3rd Item"   ]
```

There may be one Row that looks like this :

```
    [   ]
```

And you cannot sort with operator.itemgetter unless every row in that nested list has an item at index number 0 ( or another column number you choose to input in your itemgetter ).